# CROSSFADE SOUND AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I'm an AS 3.0 project where I'm getting into an array sounds to compose a particular set of phrases. The problem is that it sounds too much shock and wanted to make a crossfade effect to better attach a word to each other.
My problem is that I can not join them because every sound played one after another, is there any way to merge that can reach the end of a sound with the beginning of the next?

Thank you very much.

---

The code I'm working with is something like this:

```
for (iii = 0; iii < numpalabras; iii ++)
{ 
 if (abuscar2 = abuscarArray[iii])
  {
   vocaliza(abuscar2, iii);
  }
}

iii = 0;
localSound = lossonidosArray[iii];
var soundTrans:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform;
soundTrans=SoundMixer.soundTransform;
soundTrans.volume=1;
soundTrans.pan=0;
elcanal.soundTransform = soundTrans;
elcanal = localSound.play(85, 0, soundTrans);   
elcanal.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, locutapalabra);
}

function locutapalabra(event:Event)
{
if (iii < (ii))
{
  iii=iii+1;
  localSound = lossonidosArray[iii];
  var soundTrans:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform;
  soundTrans=SoundMixer.soundTransform;
  soundTrans.volume=1;
  soundTrans.pan=0;
  elcanal.soundTransform = soundTrans;
  elcanal = localSound.play(85, 0, soundTrans);
  elcanal.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, locutapalabra);
}

function vocaliza(abuscar2, iii)
{
if (datosXML.palabras.(palabra == abuscar2).palabra == abuscar2)
 {
  ii++;
  elfic = "mp3/" + datosXML.palabras.(palabra == abuscar2).fichero;
  var elsonido :Sound = new Sound();
  elsonido.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorprogreso);
  var laurl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(elfic);
  elsonido.load(laurl);
  lossonidosArray[ii] = elsonido;
 }
}
```

I am new to AS 3.0 programming and I do not get clear my code to make the words come together with each other, because I get to build such phrases of several words.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000) //set to how long to wait
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, nextSound);

function nextSound(e:Event):void
{
   listenForNextSound(); //this is where you play your next sound
}
```

`timer` is a timer variable, and when 3 seconds pass (or however long you want) the next sound will start playing.

To make your `timer` variable a bit more accurate, you can make it the duration of the sound by listening for the `COMPLETE` Event:

```
yourTimer.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function() { 
timer.delay = yourTimer.length - howMuchTimeBefore; 
});
```

Comment: Well, I understand that in this way can make it sound as event duration (the length of the sound) but I can not get to make it a little smaller. To take an example, I recorded several words each in a mp3 file, each lasts and I say them all together, instead of saying one after another, I need to be more human, almost every word go together to the next as we do verbally. Also some sounds have a few milliseconds at the beginning and end of the mp3 that I have not gotten them out, so it would be good to make that fade between a sound and the next.

Thank you.

Comment: @ManuelSeijasCortés I edited it, as you can see, replace the howMuchTimeBefore variable with how much time before the length of the sound, if it's replaced with 1000, it will play the next sound a second before the end of the one before.  Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For cross-fading, you can use a tween library (like [greensock](http://greensock.com)) to tween the volume of the sound channel:

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound(...);

// start volume at 0
var soundChannel = sound.play(0, 0, new SoundTransform(0));

// tween volume to 1
TweenMax.to(soundChannel, 1, { volume: 1 } );

// half a second before the sound is complete, tween volume to 0
TweenMax.to(soundChannel, .5, {volume: 0, delay:(sound.length/1000)-.5});
```